# PictureBox Display Image

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview with results from image search in various folders and subfolders. My problem is that I want a picturebox to display those image files. When I double click on a row where a image is on root path, that image is displayed. Its Ok. But when I double click on a row where a image is on a subfolder, inside that root path, it is not shown. Someone can help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace _myfiles
{
    public partial class FormFotos1 : Form
    {
        public FormFotos1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void FormFotos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // se pretendermos pesquisar em várias pastas
            List<string> diretorios = new List<string>()
            {@"\\server01\folder1\folder2\folder3"};

            // se pretendermos pesquisar as várias extensões
            List<string> extensoes = new List<string>()
            {".jpg",".bmp",".png",".tiff",".gif"};

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Nome do ficheiro");
            table.Columns.Add("->Duplo clique-<");

            foreach (string diretorio in diretorios)
            {
                var ficheiros = Directory.EnumerateFiles(diretorio, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
                    Where(r => extensoes.Contains(Path.GetExtension(r.ToLower())));

                foreach (var ficheiro in ficheiros)
                    table.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(ficheiro));
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }
        private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormFotos2 myForm = new FormFotos2();
            string imageName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            Image img;
            img = Image.FromFile(@"\\server01\folder1\folder2\folder3\" + imageName);
            myForm.pictureBox1.Image = img;
            myForm.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a third column in your table where you store the fullpath to the image file. This column could be hidden in the grid but when you double click the row you retrieve the fullpath from this hidden column

Comment: Something you have top fix are the paths, you should remove one '\' from @"\server01\folder1\folder2\folder3" and @"\server01\folder1\folder2\folder3\"

Comment: @Adnand this appears to be a sharename. In this case It is correct

Comment: Yes. It is a sharename.

Comment: Ok. Nice. That is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a third column to your table where you will store the full filename of the image. This column will be hidden on the DataGridView but is still there and you can use its content instead of building everytime the path to your files

```
private void FormFotos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // se pretendermos pesquisar em várias pastas
    List<string> diretorios = new List<string>()
    {@"\\server01\folder1\folder2\folder3"};

    // se pretendermos pesquisar as várias extensões
    List<string> extensoes = new List<string>()
    {".jpg",".bmp",".png",".tiff",".gif"};

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Nome do ficheiro");
    table.Columns.Add("->Duplo clique-<");
    table.Columns.Add("fullpath");
    foreach (string diretorio in diretorios)
    {
        var ficheiros = Directory.EnumerateFiles(diretorio, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
            Where(r => extensoes.Contains(Path.GetExtension(r.ToLower())));

        foreach (var ficheiro in ficheiros)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row[0] = Path.GetFileName(ficheiro);
            row[2] = ficheiro;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
}

private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormFotos2 myForm = new FormFotos2();
    string imageName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    Image img;
    img = Image.FromFile(imageName);
    myForm.pictureBox1.Image = img;
    myForm.ShowDialog();
}
```